# HighCharts: Basic line chart doesn't show first label on the X-axis

Tags: highcharts

Below is the code of my graph and problem is it doesn't show first label on the x-axis. I have tried all the options like showFirstLabel and startOnTick set to true. Still not showing.

```
  var my_chart = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'divSigninGraph',
           marginTop: 5,
            fontFamily: 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                display: 'none'
            }
        },
         legend: {
        enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 3000
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Your Progress',
                color: '#27aae2',
                data: [7, 0, 1, 19, 50, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 6, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 9, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
            }
           ],
        xAxis: {
        startOnTick:true,
        showFirstLabel: true,
        endOnTick : true,
        showLastLabel:true,

           categories: ['Jun 24', 'Jun 25', 'Jun 26', 'Jun 27', 'Jun 28', 'Jun 29', 'Jun 30', 'Jul  1', 'Jul  2', 'Jul  3', 'Jul  4', 'Jul  5', 'Jul  6', 'Jul  7', 'Jul  8', 'Jul  9', 'Jul 10', 'Jul 11', 'Jul 12', 'Jul 13', 'Jul 14', 'Jul 15', 'Jul 16', 'Jul 17', 'Jul 18', 'Jul 19', 'Jul 20', 'Jul 21', 'Jul 22', 'Jul 23', 'Jul 24'],
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                rotation: -90,
                step: 30,                     
                style: {
                    font: 'normal 9px Arial'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
    };
    new Highcharts.Chart(my_chart);
```

[image]

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems it is workin [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gBWCz/) ...

Comment: What is the version of Highchart you are using ?

Comment: I have added the latest js and it is working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works properly: `jsfiddle.net/FhhaK/2/`

Mae sure you have latest version of Highcharts.

Comment: Pawel/ Pierre , it works fine when I add it to fiddle. But it doesn't show correct in my aspx page. It shows like I have attached here this image. Any other thing I need to check for this? Any dimensions or .. ?

Comment: Good catch Pawel.. I have added below latest js to my code and it worked fine..<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"> </script> ....... Thank you so much...